# Woocommerce: How to change the url where a standard button routes the user

Tags: woocommerce

Aim for an one-page `Woocommerce site`, meaning the user shall stay on the archive page, even if the buttons "Apply coupon" or "Update cart" are pushed. Currently the user is routed to domain/cart.

Is there a way to change these standard Woocommerce buttons?
If you have some code suggestion, can you please also let me know which file I shall change? (in child theme copies of course)

Currently the standard Woocommerce routes the user to domain/cart, when one of these buttons is pushed. Desired behavior is that it stays on the archive page.